# Extract part of the code and parse HTML in bash

Tags: bash, sed, html-parsing

I have external HTML site and I need to extract data from the table on that site. However source of the HTML website has wrong formatting except the table in the code, so I can not use

```
xmllint --html --xpath <xpath> <file>
```

because it does not work properly, when HTML formatting on the site is broken.

My idea was to use curl and delete code above and below the table. When table is extracted, code is clean and it fits to **xmllint** tool (I can use xpath then). However delete everything above the match is challenging for shell as you can see here: [Sed doesn't backtrack: once it's processed a line, it's done.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29906/delete-range-of-lines-above-pattern-with-sed-or-awk)
Is there a way how to extract only the code of the table from the HTML site in bash? Suposse, code has this structure.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum ....</p>
  <table class="my-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
<p>... dolor.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And I need output like this to parse data properly:

```
  <table class="my-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Please, do not give me minus because of trying to use bash.

Comment: You can check this article: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/using-linux-shell-web-scraping/

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the HTML with HTML-Tidy http://www.html-tidy.org/

Comment: I have tried "tidy -ashtml page.html -output page2.html" but unfortunately it returns "This document has errors that must be fixed before using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version." It need to be fully automatic. Anyway thanks. @Dan-Dev

Comment: @Dan-Dev Thank you very much, after all tidy helped. I used force-output and then xmllint could read html file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I will break down the answer which I tried using [`xmllint`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) which supports a `--html` flag for parsing `html` files

Firstly you can check the sanity of your HTML file by parsing it as below which confirms if the file is as per the standards or throws out errors if seen:-

```
$ xmllint --html YourHTML.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum ....</p>
  <table class="my-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
<p>... dolor.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

with my original `YourHTML.html` file just being the input HTML file in your question.

Now for the value extraction part:-

Starting the file parsing from root-node to the `table` node (`//html/body/table`) and running `xmllint` in HTML parser & interactive shell mode (`xmllint --html --shell`)

Running the command plainly produces a result,

```
$ echo "cat //html/body/table" |  xmllint --html --shell YourHTML.html
/ >  -------
<table class="my-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
/ >
```

Now removing the special characters using `sed` i.e. `sed '/^\/ >/d'` produces

```
$ echo "cat //html/body/table" |  xmllint --html --shell YourHTML.html | sed '/^\/ >/d'
<table class="my-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

which is the output structure as you expected. Tested on `xmllint: using libxml version 20900`

I will go one more step ahead, and if you want to fetch the values within the `table` tag, you can apply the `sed` command to extract them as

```
$ echo "cat //html/body/table" |  xmllint --html --shell YourHTML.html | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | xargs
Company Contact
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, when HTML valid and it is not broken. But I can not apply this in my case (sorry for simplified misleading example). Obviously, lot of web pages does not have valid html code, so it would not allow me to parse data from them. Let suppose, that only valid code is inside the table. Unfortunately, I must admit, bash is not really suitable to extract part of the code on webpage which does not follow W3C standards. Do you know about any option how to extract table different way?

Comment: I found after all, that this solution works perfectly with the @Dan-Dev recommendation to use tidy with option force-output: yes

Comment: xmllint is useless for real world html. It will fail on most websites

Answer (score 4):

For your purposes a quick solution would be a 1-liner:

```
sed -n '/<table class="my-table">/,/<\/table>/p'  <file>
```

Explanation:
print everything between two specified tags, in this case `<table>`

You could also easily make a tag variable for e.g `<body>` or `<p>` and change the output on the fly. But the above solution gives what you asked for without external tools.