# How to scrape a HTML table and print it on terminal using Bash?

Tags: html, bash, awk, web-scraping, xmlstarlet

I've been trying to scrape (using BASH) the table from this website: http://www.tesouro.fazenda.gov.br/tesouro-direto-precos-e-taxas-dos-titulos , which are the current prices for Brazil Government Bonds. I want to develop a script that gives me the same table, formatted to terminal output so I can assign it to an alias and get the prices quickly (and publish it on github so others can use it as well, or even use it on other code).

What I've done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
url="http://www.tesouro.fazenda.gov.br/tesouro-direto-precos-e-taxas-dos-titulos"

lynx -source "$url" |
grep -o '<tbody>.*</tbody>' |
#gets the entire line
sed 's/\(<tr>\|<\/tr>\)//g' |  
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
#cleans the html tags
```

Running "./script.sh > file.txt" gives me the output:

> Investir  Mercado Aberto 9h30min às 18h Preços e taxas dos títulos públicos disponíveis para investir     Título  Vencimento Indexador  Taxa de Rendimento (% a.a.)  Valor Mínimo  Preço Unitário  Indexados ao IPCA    Tesouro IPCA+ 2024 (NTNB Princ) 15/08/2024 5,05 R$43,62 R$2.181,47   Tesouro IPCA+ 2035 (NTNB Princ) 15/05/2035 5,48 R$35,96 R$1.198,82   Tesouro IPCA+ 2045 (NTNB Princ) 15/05/2045 5,48 R$35,21 R$704,20   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2026 (NTNB) 15/08/2026 5,10 R$32,72 R$3.272,36   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2035 (NTNB) 15/05/2035 5,35 R$32,63 R$3.263,54   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2050 (NTNB) 15/08/2050 5,42 R$33,55 R$3.355,64  Prefixados    Tesouro Prefixado 2020 (LTN) 01/01/2020 8,40 R$33,84 R$846,13   Tesouro Prefixado 2023 (LTN) 01/01/2023 10,20 R$30,58 R$611,76   Tesouro Prefixado com Juros Semestrais 2027 (NTNF) 01/01/2027 10,36 R$30,69 R$1.023,16  Indexados à Taxa Selic    Tesouro Selic 2023 (LFT) 01/03/2023 0,00 R$92,38 R$9.238,83        Resgatar  Mercado Aberto 9h30min às 18h   Preços e taxas dos títulos públicos disponíveis para resgatar      Título  Vencimento Indexador  Taxa de Rendimento (% a.a.)  Preço Unitário  Indexados ao IPCA    Tesouro IPCA+ 2019 (NTNB Princ) 15/05/2019 2,93 R$2.907,76   Tesouro IPCA+ 2024 (NTNB Princ) 15/08/2024 5,17 R$2.164,92   Tesouro IPCA+ 2035 (NTNB Princ) 15/05/2035 5,60 R$1.175,37   Tesouro IPCA+ 2045 (NTNB Princ) 15/05/2045 5,60 R$682,63   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2020 (NTNB) 15/08/2020 4,17 R$3.221,84   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2024 (NTNB) 15/08/2024 5,08 R$3.240,43   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2026 (NTNB) 15/08/2026 5,22 R$3.246,88   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2035 (NTNB) 15/05/2035 5,47 R$3.221,99   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2045 (NTNB) 15/05/2045 5,56 R$3.231,12   Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2050 (NTNB) 15/08/2050 5,54 R$3.298,33  Prefixados    Tesouro Prefixado 2018 (LTN) 01/01/2018 7,06 R$994,86   Tesouro Prefixado 2019 (LTN) 01/01/2019 7,13 R$929,11   Tesouro Prefixado 2020 (LTN) 01/01/2020 8,52 R$844,19   Tesouro Prefixado 2021 (LTN) 01/01/2021 9,46 R$757,85   Tesouro Prefixado 2023 (LTN) 01/01/2023 10,32 R$608,40   Tesouro Prefixado com Juros Semestrais 2021 (NTNF) 01/01/2021 9,28 R$1.060,17   Tesouro Prefixado com Juros Semestrais 2023 (NTNF) 01/01/2023 10,08 R$1.039,70   Tesouro Prefixado com Juros Semestrais 2025 (NTNF) 01/01/2025 10,37 R$1.025,50   Tesouro Prefixado com Juros Semestrais 2027 (NTNF) 01/01/2027 10,48 R$1.016,60  Indexados à Taxa Selic   Tesouro Selic 2021 (LFT) 01/03/2021 0,04 R$9.226,94   Tesouro Selic 2023 (LFT) 01/03/2023 0,04 R$9.219,57  Indexados ao IGP-M   Tesouro IGPM+ com Juros Semestrais 2021 (NTNC) 01/04/2021 4,42 R$3.756,86   Tesouro IGPM+ com Juros Semestrais 2031 (NTNC) 01/01/2031 5,33 R$5.863,43

which is in portuguese, so I'll try my best to help getting helped:

1. Everything, unfortunately, is in one single line, I believe it's because the HTML file is this way and grep gets it.
2. The important data is right after the last word "investir" and the first "Resgatar". These are the bonds available to buy from the government.
3. Between the last word "resgatar" and the end of table, are the bonds which are no longer available for buying, but you can sell back to the government anytime until due date.
4. The table field titles are "Titulo - Vencimento - Taxa de Rendimento (% a.a.) - Preço Unitario", which translates to "Title - Due date - Interst Rate (% year) - Unit Price"

If you guys could help me at least removing these unwanted 'description words' between the table titles (which is, to say, from beginning of line until first ocurrence of "Título" and then from the first "Resgatar" until the next ocurrence of "Título"), I believe this tool could help others as well.

From there, I can try to AWK my way out of the rest of the file and format the way I want. I just need to remove these, which I haven't been able to do, despite searching a couple of questions here in stack.
Also, if someone has a more smart way of doing what I intend to do, please feel free to discard everything dumb I've done and suggest a more intelligent approach in BASH!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools to manipulate structured data.  You should do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001475/extract-part-of-the-code-and-parse-html-in-bash

Comment: Thanks! I will study this solution then!

Comment: @ViníciusR.Sanches, so you want to parse the whole `<table>` contents? But there are table cells which occupy the entire row, like `Indexados ao IPCA` ... how should they be treated. Post a fragment of the final output. The solution won't be difficult

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Oh, I see. These rows are subtitles, each one meaning which index they are bound to. In the example, "indexados ao IPCA" means "indexed to the inflation rate". I imagine the output could be something like for each content between <tr> </tr>, print in a new line, like this:
`
    Indexados ao IPCA \n
    Tesouro IPCA+ 2024 (NTNB Princ)\tab15/08/2024\tab5,06\tabR$43,60\tabR$2.180,09
`

Comment: @ViníciusR.Sanches, how about posting a formatted fragment of the final output to the question?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Um, I'm not sure if I know how to do that in here, my comments keep getting badly formatted. But in any case, I wanted to print it in terminal structured just like the formatting of the table on the website, only with tabs and newlines instead of HTML tags. The problem is in the strings that aren't inside table cells, I don't know the proper command to remove them and be left with only table elements

Comment: That's why you should [edit] the question instead of trying to add information in comments. Have you looked at the [W3C HTML-XML-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/)? They were created for command-line processing of HTML and XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Example:

```
wget -q -O - 'http://www.tesouro.fazenda.gov.br/tesouro-direto-precos-e-taxas-dos-titulos' |\
  xmlstarlet format --recover --html 2>/dev/null |\
  xmlstarlet select --html --template --value-of "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='listing0' or @class='listing' or @class='listing ']" |\
  paste -d ";" - - - - - |\
  column -s ";" -t
```

Output:

```
Tesouro IPCA+ 2024 (NTNB Princ)                     15/08/2024  5,06   R$43,60  R$2.180,09
Tesouro IPCA+ 2035 (NTNB Princ)                     15/05/2035  5,48   R$35,96  R$1.198,82
Tesouro IPCA+ 2045 (NTNB Princ)                     15/05/2045  5,48   R$35,21  R$704,20
Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2026 (NTNB)      15/08/2026  5,10   R$32,72  R$3.272,36
Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2035 (NTNB)      15/05/2035  5,35   R$32,63  R$3.263,54
Tesouro IPCA+ com Juros Semestrais 2050 (NTNB)      15/08/2050  5,41   R$33,60  R$3.360,49
Tesouro Prefixado 2020 (LTN)                        01/01/2020  8,38   R$33,85  R$846,45
Tesouro Prefixado 2023 (LTN)                        01/01/2023  10,20  R$30,58  R$611,76
Tesouro Prefixado com Juros Semestrais 2027 (NTNF)  01/01/2027  10,37  R$30,67  R$1.022,61
Tesouro Selic 2023 (LFT)                            01/03/2023  0,00   R$92,38  R$9.238,83
```

I inserted `xmlstarlet format --recover --html 2>/dev/null` because HTML from this URL is not valid.

---

See: `xmlstarlet select --help`, `man paste` and `man column`

Comment: wow, thank you so much. This was exactly what I was trying to do. I will study xmlstarlet more, I didn't know it