# How to grep/sed between html tags if between tags is value

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I'm trying to grep/sed html tags that have number 1550 inside of them.
I have a json response that contains response with multiple

tags and values inside of them, I want to grep only

that have 1550 somewhere inside of them. Like for example I have file

`<p>Okay</p><p>Okay/1550/dadajd</p><p>jey/ok/jeu</p>`

and I want to grep only this `<p>Okay/1550/dadajd</p>`

I tried `grep -o '<p>.*1550.*</p>'`
but it greps everything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a non-greedy match in grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30130912/3832970)

Comment: Use a better tool for the job. Possible duplicate of [Parse HTML using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25358698/608639), [Extract part of the code and parse HTML in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41001475/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following pattern:

```
grep -o '<p>[^<>]*1550[^<>]*</p>'
```