# How to cut from file and put the words in the same line Linux

Tags: bash

So I have this line of code:

```
grep "Cx Ações Europa Soc Resp" -A 7 teste.html | tr -s " " "#" | cut -f 2 -d"#" | tr -s "Cx" "\b" | tr -s "</td><td>" "\b"
```

and the output is:

```
8,2524
8,1215
-9,25%
-5,32%
```

but when I do `td -s "\n" " "` only shows me the last value -5,32%

How can I do to show every values like this `8,2524 8,1215 -9,25% -5,32`

I need the values on same line because I need to make a echo with the values like

```
8,2524|8,1215|-9,25%|-5,32
```

Comment: Get a HTML parser; everything else (regexes and cut and such) is too brittle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001475/extract-part-of-the-code-and-parse-html-in-bash

Comment: example of expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your need, you want to join/concatenate the output lines.

- `tr '\n' ' '`
- `sed 's/\n/ /'`
- etc.

Comment: Now I have this `grep "Cx Ações Europa Soc Resp" -A 7 teste.html | tr -s " " "#" | cut -f 2 -d"#" | tr -s "Cx" "\b" | tr -s "</td><td>" "\b"` and the output is  **ON TABLE**                                      
8,2524
8,1215
-9,25%
-5,32%

Comment: You're replacing each character of the list, `</td>` or `Cx`, with '\b' So the result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

using `awk`

```
 awk '{a=$0" "a;} END {print a} '
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it