# Web scraping with bash how to write script

Tags: bash, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape with bash https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html and filter the menu on the left to display the deal name and price. I need help please let me know how to write a bash script to get the name and price of the deals. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Also why do you have `python` tag, if your question is about clean `bash`?

Comment: This is too broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` to grep the html file for the names and prices. Every deal name is enclosed in an `h5` element with class `product-title`, and every price is enclosed in a `span` element with class `starting-price`. Look through some examples on this answer [1], and that should get you going.

[1] [Extract part of the code and parse HTML in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001475/extract-part-of-the-code-and-parse-html-in-bash)

Comment: Hey, Please it would be great if you can help me with the code. Please do right a sample script.

Answer (score 0):

**beware website formatting can vary, so just working with line numbers may not work. if you don't want to use HTML tag reader you can do it all in in script language**

(do the following in bash with arrays or just use variables if you want to make it run with other shells too)

- **use `curl` to download HTML file**
  (`$0` = name of script, used for temporary file name here)

  ```
  curl "${URL}${LINE}" > "${0%.*}.tmp~"
  ```
- use string manipulation `${LINE##*&}` to print only `'catId=12'` from your URI
- use `grep` to search for string `'catId=12'`, use `-w` flag to match exact phrase
- **pipe** the output to another `grep` and search for item name `'<span.*</span>'`
- use `cut` to extract value of item into **file name**

  ```
  file="$(grep -w "${LINE##*&}" "${0%.*}.tmp~" | grep -o '<span.*</span>' | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1)"
  ```
- convert the item name into some handy file name (because we don't like chars like `*` or `'` in file names
- use a whitelist for alpanumeric characters, spaces (and `.` `_` `-`) and delete all forbidden characters with string manipulation
- replace all spaces with `_`
- iterate over file name and replace all chains of `___`  with single `_`

  ```
  file="${file//[^[:alnum:]^.^\/^_^\ -]/}"
  file="${file// /_}"
  while [[ "${file}" =~ "__" ]]
    do
      file="${file//__/_}"
  done
  ```
- use `grep` to **search** for `<div class="panel panel-default panel-product">` and save the **byte offset** into `product_offset_1` - `product_offset_5`
- save file size in bytes as last `product_offset_6`
- tell `grep` to **count** matches into variable `j`

  ```
  product_offset=()
  for offset in $(grep -bha '<div class="panel panel-default panel-product">' "${file}.html" | cut -d: -f1)
    do
       product_offset+=($offset)
  done
  # file size in bytes as last product_offset
  product_offset+=($(stat -c%s "${file}.html"))
  # count matches
  j=$(grep -hac '<div class="panel panel-default panel-product">' "${file}.html")
  ```
- make a **loop** over `product_offset_1` - `product_offset_6` and calculate length in bytes
- **within the loop**: use `dd` to print only part of file between offset_1 < offset_2

  ```
  i=0
  while [ $i -lt $j ]
    do
      # calculate product_offset
      beg=${product_offset[$i]}
      end=${product_offset[$((i+1))]}
      len=$(expr ${end:-0} - ${beg:-0})

      # print only part of file
      dd if="${file}.html" bs=1 skip=$beg count=$len status=none

      i=$((i+1))
  done
  ```
- **within the loop: search** for `<h5 class="product-title">` for each part
- use `cut` to extract **value** of `product-title` into `title_1` - `title_5`

  ```
  title=()
      # search title within product_offset
      item="$(dd if="${file}.html" bs=1 skip=${beg:-0} count=${len:-0} status=none | grep '<h5 class="product-title">' | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1)"
      title+=("$item")
  ```
- **within the loop: search** for `<span class="starting-price">` for each part
- use `cut` to extract **value** of `starting-price` into `price_1` - `price_5`
  (same as above)

  ```
  price=()
       # search price within product_offset
      item="$(dd if="${file}.html" bs=1 skip=${beg:-0} count=${len:-0} status=none | grep '<span class="starting-price">' | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1)"
      price+=("$item")
  ```
- finally, make a loop over all variables and use `$i` for the variable names
- print array title + price into file (or do this within the same loop above)

  ```
  # read array title + price    
  i=0
  while [ $i -lt $j ]
    do
      # echo -e "(${title[$i]}, ${price[$i]})\n" | tee -a "${file}.txt"
      printf "%s-\tName:\t%s\n\tPrice:\t%s\n\n" $((i+1)) "${title[$i]}" "${price[$i]}" | tee -a "${file}.txt"
      i=$((i+1))
  done
  ```

---

**for the better overview all in your script together**

```
#!/bin/bash

# just for demo
> URI.txt
URI='?daypartId=1&catId='
URL=https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html

# just for demo
for id in 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 11 12 14
  do
    echo -e "${URI}${id}" >> URI.txt
done

ARRAY=()
while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]
do
    [ "$LINE" ] && ARRAY+=("$LINE")
done < URI.txt

for LINE in "${ARRAY[@]}"
  do
    # curl into file main.tmp~
    echo -e "${URL}${LINE}"
    curl "${URL}${LINE}" > "${0%.*}.tmp~" 2> /dev/null

    # get item name and convert into simple file name
    file="$(grep -w "${LINE##*&}" "${0%.*}.tmp~" | grep -o '<span.*</span>' | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1)"
    file="${file//[^[:alnum:]^.^\/^_^\ -]/}"
    file="${file// /_}"
    while [[ "${file}" =~ "__" ]]
      do
        file="${file//__/_}"
    done

    # fallback file name
    [ "$file" ] || file="file${LINE##*&}"

    # rename main.tmp~ into Deals.html and create empty file Deals.txt
    mv -f "${0%.*}.tmp~" "${file}.html" > "${file}.txt"

    # declare arrays
    product_offset=()
    title=()
    price=()

    for offset in $(grep -bha '<div class="panel panel-default panel-product">' "${file}.html" | cut -d: -f1)
      do
         product_offset+=($offset)
    done
    # file size in bytes as last product_offset
    product_offset+=($(stat -c%s "${file}.html"))
    # count matches
    j=$(grep -hac '<div class="panel panel-default panel-product">' "${file}.html")

    # write array title + price from Deals.html    
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $j ]
      do
        # calculate product_offset
        beg=${product_offset[$i]}
        end=${product_offset[$((i+1))]}
        len=$(expr ${end:-0} - ${beg:-0})

        # search title within product_offset
        item="$(dd if="${file}.html" bs=1 skip=${beg:-0} count=${len:-0} status=none | grep '<h5 class="product-title">' | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1)"
        title+=("$item")

        # search price within product_offset
        item="$(dd if="${file}.html" bs=1 skip=${beg:-0} count=${len:-0} status=none | grep '<span class="starting-price">' | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1)"
        price+=("$item")

        i=$((i+1))
    done

    echo -e "################################################\n#"
    echo -e "# ${file//_/ }\n#"
    echo -e "################################################\n"

    # read array title + price    
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $j ]
      do
        # echo -e "(${title[$i]}, ${price[$i]})\n" | tee -a "${file}.txt"
        printf "%s-\tName:\t%s\n\tPrice:\t%s\n\n" $((i+1)) "${title[$i]}" "${price[$i]}" | tee -a "${file}.txt"
        i=$((i+1))
    done
done

exit 0
```

---

**Happy coding and Good Luck!**

Comment: `var = curl https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html"$LINE" | grep '<span>.*</span>' | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' > $var.txt`  I want to save the data from curl into a file with the name that grep grabs. Like if the `grep` command fetches `beverages` then it should make a file called `beverage.txt`

Comment: i hope you understand why it is important to check position of each title + price and preserve the pairing. there are several methods to do this, this is just one simple idea. (imagine your grep gives 5x title + 8x price how will you pairing once separated in different text files?)

Comment: Any idea how to do it? like fetch the data (Title) into a variable and then make the file of that variable?

Comment: updated with your desired output and saves everything into file "beverages.txt"