# Loading xml file and mapping given columns before inserting data into Hive Table

Tags: shell, apache-spark, hive, oozie-workflow

I want to load the XML file into hive columns, but before that I need do some mapping of some fields using a given map values.

Example:

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
      <FirstName>Test1</FirstName>
      <LastName>toto1</LastName>
      <ContactNo>111</ContactNo>
      <Email>toto1@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Bangalore</City>
           <State>Karnataka</State>
           <Zip>560212</Zip>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <FirstName>Test2</FirstName>
      <LastName>toto2</LastName>
      <ContactNo>222</ContactNo>
      <Email>toto2@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Bangalore</City>
           <State>Karnataka</State>
           <Zip>545454</Zip>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <FirstName>Test3</FirstName>
      <LastName>toto3</LastName>
      <ContactNo>333</ContactNo>
      <Email>toto3@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Bangalore</City>
           <State>Karnataka</State>
           <Zip>36363</Zip>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

I did this to load file in Hive and it works for me.

add jar ${projet}/datagaps_xml_traite/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Employee;

```
CREATE external TABLE Employee(
(FirstName STRING,LastName STRING,ContactNo STRING,Email STRING,City STRING,State STRING,Zip STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
"column.xpath.FirstName"="/Employee/FirstName/text()",
"column.xpath.LastName"="//Employee/LastName/text()",
"column.xpath.ContactNo"="/Employee/ContactNo/text()",
"column.xpath.City"="/Employee/Address/City/text()",
"column.xpath.State"="/Employee/Address/State/text()",
"column.xpath.Zip"="/Employee/Address/Zip/text()",
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/data/myFile.xml/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<Employee",
"xmlinput.end"="</Employee>" ) 
;
```

Now, I have a Map like this:

```
contactNo,identif
111,       XXX
222,       YYY
333,       ZZZ
```

I want to map each contactNo with its identif and insert The identif value in Hive.

Could someOne please guide me to solve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62204377